# jQuery function on initial home page load only

Tags: jquery, animation

I know that Apple had done this on their homepage for the Beatles.. well, at least I think they did.

but, I have an animation happening to my header and navigation links on my webpage that I want to only animate on the load of the home page only. Now, I know I can specifically add the JS to the home page but is there also a way to limit the animation to only work when a visitor FIRST visits the site in one session?

Answer (score 0):

You can record visits in a cookie, then interrogate that cookie

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to use cookies for this.  Here's an explanation of how they work: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html.

Basically, you store a boolean value once the animation is first played, and then it won't be played again until the cookie expires.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cookie via JavaScript after the initial load, and then check for that cookie in subsequent requests. If it exists, don't play the animation. If you set the cookie to expire as soon as the browser is closed, the animation will replay the next time they visit the site.

If you're using jQuery, I suggest the j[query.cookie.js](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin for handling cookie interactions.

Comment: what if the visitor returns to the site without closing the browser? :D

Comment: That's what the timeout is for.

Comment: @Andrei If they return to the site, the cookie will still exist, so the animation won't happen. That might be an acceptable behavior; it depends on what @code means by "session".

Comment: Then, what if he wants the animation to play each time you visit the site. That's what I understand. The cookie should expire when the user leaves the domain, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions, created at visits and destroyed at exits.

Cookies... they should work, but there is the time problem; whatever time-needed-to-pass-to-show-the-animation-again you choose, some visitors will receive undesired results.

Comment: If he's only working in JS though, he'd have to use cookies.  Sessions always involve the server side.

Answer (score -1):

You could use code server side be it PHP, ASP etc.  You can use a [cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or the session to store a boolean value to determine if it's the first time they've loaded the page and have your JS render your image at that time.

- User loads page
- If JS does not find cookie renders image and creates a cookie
- If JS does find cookie image is not rendered

Comment: You can set cookies with JavaScript (http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp). Server-side would only be needed for sessions.